# HA Proxy URL Rewrite/Redirect

Tags: regex, redirect, url-rewriting, url-routing, haproxy

I'm trying to rewrite a URL but so far not succeeded.

URL Access from outside - https://example.domain.com/health (Which gives 404)
Backend URL Need to redirect - http://example.domain.com/appname/health

I have multiple domains configured this HAproxy. such as example1, example2
Haproxy Ver is  1.4.22
I tried few workarounds reqrep(messed with regex I guess), redirect(can't match 404) non of them succeeded so far. Its great somebody can suggest me a workaround with regular expressions if applicable.

Comment: Please include the config.

Comment: As @TanHongTat stated, please provide what you have tried (config/etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you provided your config, however, it seems all you want is redirect a specific URL to another URL.

You can achieve this with the "[redirect](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#redirect)" keyword.

There are multiple ways you could achieve what you want, using different "redirect" keyword combination, so here's one solution:

```
frontend http
   acl is_health url_reg ^/health

   redirect prefix http://www.example.com/appname code 301 if is_health
```

and here's another:

```
frontend http
   acl is_health url /health

   redirect location http://www.example.com/appname/health code 301 if is_health
```